# Write a text using GLUT and C

Tags: c, text, glut, freeglut

I'm actually working on a game using GLUT and C and I would like to display the score on my window, I'm searching for something similar to printf so I can display my text "score" and it value that can change.

I've found a function name DrawBitmapText but whith that function I can only display text, I couldn't display a variable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf()` will create the text you want in a buffer:

```
char buf[256];
sprintf(buf, "Score: %d", score);
DrawBitmapText(..., buf);
```